# Mobile Safari rendering weird, adding extra margin in wrong place

Tags: css, safari, rendering, flexbox

Sometimes, but not always, when this one web app page loads on mobile safari there is an extra margin added that cuts into what is supposed to be a single button. It goes right through the text without affecting where the text is. If I go into the web inspector with an emulator open, and comment out basically any styling anywhere on the page the space goes away. Said space only appears on mobile safari, nowhere else. If I reload the page, sometimes it will be there, but sometimes it won't. Is this a safari rendering issue? Or something else?

The first image illustrates what it looks like on an iphone when it's working, and the second is when the weird space is being added:

[image: working]
[image: not working]

Answer (score 0):

So turns out the answer is to add the transformz(0) hack to the anchor elements (the buttons). This tricks the browser into using the gpu to render the page, not the cpu, helping performance issues on mobile especially. Great link with more info: http://aerotwist.com/blog/on-translate3d-and-layer-creation-hacks/